# Is there a common browser shortcut for jumping to a website’s search bar?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, search

I know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> moves focus to the browser address bar, and I use it all the time across browsers. What would be useful though, on sites such as this one, Amazon, or even Google, is a shortcut which moves directly to the "main" search bar at the top of the page. Is there such a thing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I also specifically want a "search" inside the amazon website:  the "/" does not work. What are they thinking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not in every situation but <kbd>/</kbd> (slash) works on **a lot** of websites like Google pages (Youtube, Gmail, Drive, Photos...), Facebook, Twitter... and brings you to that page's search box

> <kbd>/</kbd> - Search
>
> [How can I navigate Facebook with keyboard shortcuts?](https://www.facebook.com/help/156151771119453)

---

In Github you can even see the <kbd>/</kbd> shortcut on the search box

[image: Github search box]

> <kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>/</kbd>: Focus the search bar. For more information, see "[About searching on GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-searching-on-github)."
>
> [Keyboard shortcuts](https://help.github.com/en/articles/keyboard-shortcuts)

---

Same to JIRA:

[image: JIRA shortcut]

See [Jira - Using Keyboard Shortcuts](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile066/jira-agile-user-s-guide/using-keyboard-shortcuts)

---

[Infoplus](https://www.infopluscommerce.com/knowledge-base/tip-use-the-forward-slash-/-to-access-quick-search):

> Tip: Use the Forward Slash (/) to Access Quick Search

---

It also works in Google after searching: [Shortcut for Google search box](https://superuser.com/a/1642422/241386)

[image: Google press / to jump to search box]

---

<kbd>/</kbd> is also the [shortcut for "quick find" in Firefox](https://superuser.com/q/80819/241386).
If you want to do the same in Chrome you'll need [SlashSearch](https://lifehacker.com/slashsearch-adds-forward-slash-search-to-every-site-5879138)

This key probably comes from several Unix command line tools (lile `less` or `vi`) where [`/` is the search feature](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/806-7612/editorvi-62/index.html)

Answer (score 7):

Since you are using chrome, the closest thing I can think of is using an extension called [vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb/).

1. You press "f," it shows a letter (or two) in front of every field on
   the page.
2. You press that letter, and it simulates a click.

This way can achieve the desired outcome of using a shortcut to jump to the search bar, but this shortcut changes from page to page.

example : in this case you press: f followed by d
[image: vimium chrome extension]

Comment: The OP also tags Firefox and there are similar extensions like Vimium-FF

Comment: this ROCKS.  I specifically used it for _amazon_ per the OP

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Firefox, you could go to `about:config` and configure `accessibility:tabfocus` to 1.
See here for more details: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Accessibility.tabfocus

This will force the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to give focus to text fields only so most of the time, just once or few presses of the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key directs it to the search bar and other text fields.

Answer (score 2):

## Firefox

1. Jump to address bar: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
2. Input search engine keyword: <kbd><kbd>@</kbd><search-engine><kbd><Enter></kbd></kbd>
3. Input search query

**Tip**: Firefox has auto-completion after inputting <kbd>@</kbd> symbol.  A relative drop-down menu appears below the address bar that shows your choices.

### Search Settings

Add, change, or remove **search engines** and **keywords**: `about:preferences#search`

### Examples

Default Search Engine: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> `the Beatles`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Amazon: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd><kbd>@Amazon</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> `Beatles submarine`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

DuckDuckGo: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd><kbd>@d</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> `Beatles memorabilia`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

### Pros & Cons

**Pros**

```
- This will work for any search engine that can be added into Firefox in preferences.
- Defaults come with Firefox: Amazon, Google, Bing, eBay, DuckDuckGo, Wikipedia
```

**Cons**

```
- This doesn't work with websites outside of what you can add-on in Firefox's preferences.
```

You can workaround this con through:

1. <kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> search features by searching for a keyword on the webpage that sits adjacent to the search bar then <kbd>Tab</kbd>bing over.  Use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to tab backwards.
2. Use Google's `site` operator in search bar to search a given domain. `site:github.com avr assembly`

Answer (score 1):

This [userscript](https://gist.github.com/caspark/cb561ce60629dd70ee7533af54828379) adds a slash keypress event listener for google search pages.

You can use it with [Tampermonkey](http://www.tampermonkey.net) in most modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use an Extension

If using Chrome, simply install [Search Box Focus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-box-focus/amgmdnojamodmpfjaokfgpijhpcednjm). It allows you to set your own custom shortcut and works basically everywhere. On any website that has a search bar.

Answer (score 0):

depending on how you use your browser.

i. e. Google Chrome accepts it by using F6 as any default browser for the Adress Bar, any text for them will redirected to the default search engine

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Tab". After you type the website on address bar.
for example: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) then press TAB

Comment: This is what to do when you are in the address bar, not how to get to it from a browser view.